# Datastax Cassandra driver with Scala - Codecs not found

Tags: scala, cassandra, codec, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

1. Datastax driver Cassandra version: 3.3.2
2. Scala version: 2.12.4

I'm playing with creating a scala wrapper for the mappingmanager in the datastax java driver for Cassandra.

For this I have the following simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE todo (
    id UUID,
    title TEXT,
    completed boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY((id), completed, title)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (completed ASC, title ASC);
```

The createAsync, saveAsync and deleteAsync functions are working fine now. Now I want to implement the more general executeAsync functionality. Therefore I have the following code:

```
private def executeAsync(query: String, params: Any*): Future[ResultSet] = {
    params match {
      case Seq() =>
        session.executeAsync(query) // had a problem with empty params varargs
      case _ =>
        prepareAsync(query).map(preparedStatement =>
          preparedStatement.bind(
            params
              .map(x => {
                println(x) // correctly prints the param
                x.asInstanceOf[Object]
              })
          )
        ).flatMap(x => {
          println("here") // never gets printed
          session.executeAsync(x)
        })
    }
  }

  private def prepareAsync(query: String): Future[PreparedStatement] = {
    session.prepareAsync(query)
  }
```

The following query retrieves the values correctly:

```
val future: Future[List[TodoCassandra]] = customMappingManager.executeQueryAsync("SELECT * FROM todo;")
    future.onComplete {
      case Success(x) =>
        println(x)
    }
```

The following examples:

```
val future: Future[List[TodoCassandra]] = customMappingManager.executeQueryAsync("INSERT INTO todo (id, title, completed) VALUES (uuid(), ?, ?)", "prepared statement test", false)

val future: Future[List[TodoCassandra]] = customMappingManager.executeQueryAsync("INSERT INTO todo (id, completed, title) VALUES (uuid(), ?, ?)", false, "prepared statement test")

val future: Future[List[TodoCassandra]] = customMappingManager.executeQueryAsync("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE id = ?", "a8a6da8b-3d0e-40b3-99e5-fe2f664f50d0")
```

Result in:

1. Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer]) (of class scala.util.Failure)
2. Codec not found for requested operation: [boolean <-> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer]) (of class scala.util.Failure)
3. Codec not found for requested operation: [uuid <-> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer]) (of class scala.util.Failure)

Why is it always 'converting' from a scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer?
What can be the solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar problem to yours while using [Querying Cassandra from Scala](https://www.beyondthelines.net/databases/querying-cassandra-from-scala/) tutorial.

#### What is the mistake

Your `executeAsync` method looks like the one in the article and it has the same defect. Namely, during `preparedStatement.bind` you pass a `Seq[Object]`, after casting each of `Any` item to `Object`.
And this seems to fail.

#### Fix

The easy fix is, to pass this sequence as `var-args`, as the Java method actually expects.

Code:

```
def execute(statement: Future[PreparedStatement], params: Any*)
           (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext, session: Session): Future[ResultSet] = {
  val p = params.map(_.asInstanceOf[Object])
  statement
    .map(_.bind(p: _*))
    .flatMap(session.executeAsync(_))
}
```